# How to find a string in text

Tags: linq

I'm having a list

```
var library = new List<string>() { "personal assistant", "sales manager", "engineer" };
```

and a text which is declared as

```
 string target = "I'm a personal assistant to sales manager"";
```

I need to match the list with the text and should return the match count.

For the above sample i should get a **count of 2** since **target**  is having **personal assistant and sales manager.**

Comment: Have you made any attempts at a solution?

Answer (score 4):

Maybe something like this:

```
int count = library.Count(s => target.Contains(s));
```

This one doesn't check for multiple occurrences of one string, though.